# IDE development for CodeIgniter PHP framework in ECLIPSE

Tags: eclipse, codeigniter, ide, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-jdt

I am quite new to the eclipse IDE. I want to develop an IDE for codeigniter PHP framework. How I start. What is difference between Eclipse for C++ and Eclipse for Jave EE?

How I get start?
Any kind of help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since CodeIgniter is a PHP framework, you might favor using eclipse-pdt: http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project.php?id=tools.pdt

- Installation instructions: http://wiki.eclipse.org/PDT/Installation
- Downloads page: http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/downloads/
- Tutorials to help you get started: http://wiki.eclipse.org/PDT/TUTORIALS

Note that two of those links are to wiki pages.  If you find any errors or broken links or missing information, you can edit those pages to improve them for the next person who needs them.